# Jquery input field addition, maximum total

Tags: jquery, input, max, addition

I am trying to take this code and add one piece to it. I would like the #total to have a maximum number. I am not even sure how to approach this one. I have looked around the query documentation at adding a validation or something but it wasn't what I wanted. Any help would be greatly appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/anderskitson/VVkzG/1/

JQUERY:

```
$('#the_input_id').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

$('#the_input_id1').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

var updateTotal = function() {
    var input1 = parseInt($('#the_input_id').val());
    var input2 = parseInt($('#the_input_id1').val());
    if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
        $('#total').text('');
    } else {
        $('#total').text(input1 + input2);
    }
};​
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VVkzG/2/

Comment: Exactly could you place this as a answer so I could mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [**jsfiddle.net/VVkzG/2**](http://jsfiddle.net/VVkzG/2)

HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="the_input_id">
    <input type="text" id="the_input_id1">
</form>

</div>
<div id="total">

</div>​
```

Javascript

```
$('#the_input_id').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

$('#the_input_id1').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

var updateTotal = function() {
    var input1 = parseInt($('#the_input_id').val());
    var input2 = parseInt($('#the_input_id1').val());
    if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
        $('#total').text('');
    } else {
        var max = 500;
        var total = input1 + input2;

        if(total > max) {
            $('#total').text('The maximum is '+max);
        } else {
             $('#total').text(total);
        }


    }
};​
```

Comment: Please post your code in your answer, some day jsfiddle might not be there.